# Push styled storm spout

Tags: push, apache-storm

Am a newbie in Storm and have been exploring its features to match our CEP requirements. Different examples which I have stumbled implements spouts as a polling service from a message broker, database. How to implement a push based spout i.e. Thrift server running inside a spout? How shall I make my clients aware of where my spouts are running, so that they can push data on it?

Comment: why not let them push data to a queue as @Gordon mentioned .. n then u consume and feed the message to ur spouts ... using something like [storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki) with a message queue like [Kakfka](http://kafka.apache.org/) can make your life much better I believe .. what exactly your requirements ?

Answer (score 4):

Spouts are designed and intended to poll, so you can't push to them. However, what many people do is use things like Redis, Thrift, or Kafka as services that you can push messages to and then your spout can poll them.

Answer (score 1):

The control you have on where and when a spout runs is limited, so it's a bit of hassle to have external processes communicate directly with spouts. It certainly is possible, but it's not the simplest solution.

The standard solution is to push messages to some external message queue and let your spouts poll this message queue.

There are implementations of spouts that do exactly this for commonly used message queue services, such as Kafka, Kestrel and JMS, in [storm-contrib](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a whole lot of experience with either Storm or Kafka/Kestrel or CEP, in general but I am looking for a similar solution - push to a Storm spout. How about using a load-balancer between event source and the Storm cluster? For my use case of pushing Syslog messages from rsyslog to Storm, a load-balancer can keep track of what Storm nodes are running a listening spout and which ones are down and also distribute incoming load based on different parameters. I am less inclined to introduce another layer like a message bus between the source and spout.

Edit: I read your blog and to summarize, if the only problem with a listening spout is how would a source find it then a message bus might be the wrong answer. There are simpler/better solutions to direct network traffic at a receiver based on simple network status or higher app level logic. But yes, if you want to use all the additional message bus features then obviously Kafka/Kestrel would be good options.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a typical usage of Storm, obviously you can't bind multiple instances of the spout on the same machine to the same port. In distributed setup it would be good idea to store API's current IP address and port e.g. to ZooKeeper and then balancer which would forward requests to your API.

Here's a project with simple REST API on Storm:

https://github.com/timjstewart/restexpress-storm